# Could someone help to explain this strange behaviour when Java Socket OutpurStream's send buffer is full and write operation supposed to be blocked?

Tags: java, sockets, block

I'm reading the book Tcp Ip Sockets in Java. It says that when the sending buffer is full, a call to the Socket's OutputSream.write() will block until space becomes available. I wrote a test which shows strange behaviour. 
Here is the server side code.

```
public class SocketServer {
public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocketServer.class);
public static final int PORT = 8081;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    System.out.println(in.read());
    System.out.println("getReceiveBufferSize " + clientSocket.getReceiveBufferSize());

    while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(12000);
    }
}
}
```

And here is the client side code.

```
public class SocketClient {
public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocketClient.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", SocketServer.PORT));
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    System.out.println("SendBufferSize " + socket.getSendBufferSize());
    int count = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    out.write(1);
    LOGGER.info("{} bytes", i + 1);
    }
    LOGGER.info("send over!");
}
}
```

I run the server and the client. The client keeps sending a single byte to the server and prints the counter fastly. When the counter goes to 195224, it slows down. It write a byte, stops for some seconds and keepd going, but doesn't stop.
I think if the writing client blocks, the thread would hold, logs would stop printing. What is going on and why it does not seem to be blocked? Though I know  I can not say it is not blocked by my test, I just can't explain the test.

Here is a piece of the output of the Client.

```
2017-03-07 20:28:45,455 [main] INFO  tcpip.socket.underhood.deadlock.SocketClient - 195224 bytes
2017-03-07 20:28:46,655 [main] INFO  tcpip.socket.underhood.deadlock.SocketClient - 195225 bytes
2017-03-07 20:28:49,056 [main] INFO  tcpip.socket.underhood.deadlock.SocketClient - 195226 bytes
2017-03-07 20:28:53,856 [main] INFO  tcpip.socket.underhood.deadlock.SocketClient - 195227 bytes
```

I run it with Java 8 on windows 10.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't block? You are using blocking I/O, so it will block silently. If you want to *detect* when a call would block, you actually need to use non-blocking I/O and check the return value of a write.

Comment: Because if the client blocks on writing, the next line LOGGER.info("{} bytes", i + 1); won't print on the console. But the log keeps printing, every few seconds when I think it should block.

Comment: I actually want to detect when a call would block, thought it would block when both the sending host's send buffer and the receiving server's receive buffer are full. And I run another test using non-blocking I/O as you suggested, found that the written byte count in  statement int bytes = socketChannel.write(buf); is 1 every few seconds when it should block and always be 0. The non-blocking test seems showing similar results, keeps sending when it should blocks.

Comment: The networking stack tries its best to deliver data, so there's no reason a priori that the send buffer should ever be full. There are better experts on Stackoverflow like @EJP who can hopefully weigh in.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I invite EJP to answer my question? I can't find any contact infomation in his profile, neither any stackoverflow way to do it like quora.

Comment: There is no way to do it. He just has to wander over and decide to answer.